# RequireJS - shim for CoffeeScript scripts

Tags: coffeescript, requirejs

Assuming the `sum.coffee` module is like following (without `define`):

```
sum = (a, b) ->
    return a + b
```

How to gain `shim` functionality?

```
// ...
shim: {
    'sum': {
        exports: 'sum'
    }
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiled JavaScript will have `sum` declared locally in an anonymous wrapper function. In order to make `sum` visible, you need to declare it with something like `window.sum = ...`. Then your shim should work.